# how to use restartloader in android with listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

i get data from Sqlite using Contnet provider in listview .. when new record insert in listview.. record show in listview without refreshing activity... thats why i have used restartloader but it not work for me

getAllContacts() in Database i fetch total record from database

```
    public Cursor getAllPatients(){

    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME , TAG_AGE, TAG_CITY, TAG_MOB } ,
            null, null, null, null,null);
}
```

this is content provider

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri)==PATIENTS){
        myDb.getAllPatients().setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return myDb.getAllPatients();
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is MainActivity

```
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.status_item_layout,null,new String[]{
            myDb.TAG_ID,myDb.TAG_NAME,myDb.TAG_AGE,myDb.TAG_CITY,myDb.TAG_MOB},
            new int[]{R.id.tv_status_id,R.id.tv_status_name,R.id.tv_status_age,R.id.tv_status_city,R.id.tv_status_mob,},
            0);


    if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(0) == null){
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
    }else{
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
    }

    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    apiInterface = APIClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);


    return linearLayout;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = Patients.CONTENT_URI;
    return new CursorLoader(getContext(),uri,null,null,null,null);


}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
     mAdapter.swapCursor(data);

}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
   }
```

i have not clear know about restartLoader() please tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: what do you need `restartLoader` for? see this sample provider: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/05523fb0b48280a5364908b00768ec71edb847a2/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotePadProvider.java, notice `setNotificationUri` and `notifyChange` methods

Comment: i need for data insert in listview wthout refresh the page

Comment: did you try to follow the provider i posted?

Comment: yes but the error is  Cannot resolve method 'getContentResolver()' in in my Database Class

Comment: you mean `getContext().getContentResolver()` ?

Comment: yes how can i call  getContentResolver()?

Comment: by calling `getContext().getContentResolver()` in your custom `ContentProvider`

Comment: But not resolve this in database

Comment: `"But not resolve this in database"` what are you talking about? did you see the provider i posted? just follow it, notice `setNotificationUri` and `notifyChange` methods, just do the same in your provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @psking commented, `restartLoader()` won't be necessary for updating changes in a list of cursor data since the process is replaced by [Cursor's setNotificationUri()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#setNotificationUri(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)) and [ContentResolver's notifyChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver)) methods when it comes to cursors with URIs. That said, what I would do is stick with `initLoader()` in your Activity to query the cursor data at runtime, and then use `setNotificationUri()` in your ContentProvider's `query()` method, and `notifyChange()` in your ContentProvider's `insert()` and `update()` methods to update cursor data in your list instantly as follows:

```
public class MyProvider extends ContentProvider {

    ...

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                        String sortOrder) {

        ...

        // Registers to watch a content URI for changes. This can be the URI of a specific 
        // data row (for example, "content://my_provider_type/23"), or a a generic URI for 
        // a content type.
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {

        ...

        // Notifies all listeners that the data has changed for the item content URI.
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        // Returns the new URI with the ID (of the newly inserted row) appended at the end.
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {

        ...

        // Notifies all listeners that the data at the given URI has changed should at least one
        // row be updated.
        if (rowsUpdated != 0) {
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        }

        return rowsUpdated;
    }
}
```